# Git - get a list of files that are identical between two revisions

Tags: git, git-diff

like the inverse of `git diff --name-only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by looking at unique values from `ls-tree` and `diff` with the `--name-only` options (done in one line so it's easier to search and use from history later):

```
cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD) <(git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD) | sort | uniq -u
```

In the example, the 2 revisions are HEAD and HEAD^. This produces no side effect output files.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the `comm` command and some shell commands:

```
git ls-files >files.txt
git diff --name-only >diff.txt
comm -2 -3 files.txt diff.txt
```