# Git: get list of equals files between branches

Tags: git

I know that

```
 git diff --name-status dev..master
```

nicely prints a list of files that have been chaged between branch dev and master.
How can I obtain the opposite list? I would like a list of identical files between dev and master.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git - get a list of files that are identical between two revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496041/git-get-a-list-of-files-that-are-identical-between-two-revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using git ls-files or git ls-tree, this answer has some useful code:[Git - get a list of files that are identical between two revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496041/git-get-a-list-of-files-that-are-identical-between-two-revisions)

Command would be:
cat <(git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD) <(git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD) | sort | uniq -u

But use your branch and master in place of HEAD and HEAD^